# How can i compose this MySQL query?

Tags: mysql, sql, database

The user enters from 1 to 6 words (characteristics) so the all input data is 6 words.
Here is my table:

```
----------------
| USER |  WORD |
----------------
   1   |  Green
   1   |  Black
   1   |  Red
   2   |  Green
   2   |  Gray
```

For example, array consists of 2 words: "Green", "Black". How can I receive "User=1" if the amount of conjunctions in it's characteristics is maximal. I've already tried this query:

```
// $pat - array of words
// $nums - minimal amount of conjunctions.
$nums = 0.8*count($pat)

SELECT user
FROM words
WHERE word IN ('{$pat[0]}', '{$pat[1]}','{$pat[2]}','{$pat[3]}','{$pat[4]}','{$pat[5]}')
GROUP BY `user`
HAVING count(*) >= ".$nums."
ORDER BY count(*) DESC
LIMIT 1
```

The problem is that condition `HAVING count(*) >= ".$nums."` doesn't work properly and the data is extracted even if there is only one conjunction.

Comment: What is this supposed to mean - "How can i receive "User=1" if the amount of conjunctions in it's characteristics is maximal."?

Comment: i guess he is searching for the user with the best matching of words

Comment: Show the plain text sql query, without any php code.

Comment: PS: As soon as you've hardcoded `$pat` from `0` through `5` - does it mean `$nums` is always 6?

Comment: @zerkms, the array might be shorter sometimes.

Comment: @Nobody One: so what would `$nums[5]` return if it's shorter? How about some `foreach` / `implode` to generate only necessary number of elements?

Comment: What do you mean the data is extracted when there is only one conjunction? The SQL query looks fine. Is this a problem with your PHP or SQL?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe your query is working just fine

In case when we have two words 'Green' and 'Black'

```
SELECT user
  FROM words
 WHERE word IN ('Green', 'Black')
 GROUP BY user
HAVING COUNT(*) >= (0.8 * 2)
 ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC
 LIMIT 1;
```

As expected only user 1 have have both words (which is more then 0.8 * 2):

```
| USER |
--------
|    1 |
```

Now if we have 5 words

```
SELECT user
  FROM words
 WHERE word IN ('Green', 'Black', 'Red', 'Green', 'Gray')
 GROUP BY user
HAVING COUNT(*) >= (0.8 * 5)
 ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC
 LIMIT 1;
```

The result set is empty (again as expected) since there is no user who has at least four (0.8 * 5) words.

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d90a72/11)** demo

*Therefore it seems that you're not telling us something or you real data is probably different*

---

One of the probable causes might be existence of duplicate rows with the same word for the same user. If it's the case you can either enforce a restriction with `UNIQUE` constraint on your table or using `COUNT(DISTINCT word)`

```
SELECT user
  FROM words
 WHERE word IN ('Green', 'Black')
 GROUP BY user
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT word) >= (0.8 * 2)
 ORDER BY COUNT(DISTINCT word) DESC
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ecaf0/5)** demo